# LAPACK routine works on iPhone simulator, but not on device

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, lapack, accelerate-framework

I'm using the Accelerate framework to solve a under/overdetermined system of linear equations. The routine I'm using is dgelsd_ originally from LAPACK.

```
dgelsd_( &m, &n, &nrhs, a_t, &lda, b, &ldb, s, &RCOND, &IRANK, work, &workSize, iWork, &info);
```

This works fine in the simulator, where on supplying matrices a_t and b, the result is returned correctly in b. However, when I try this on the device, the result is all zeroes.

Where could I be going wrong? I have allocated a certain amount of working memory for the routine, as required, but I ran a check with the profiler and memory doesn't seem to be the issue.

Has anyone got LAPACK routines to work correctly on the iPhone device? Thanks.

Edit: iPhone SDK version 4.2, Device iPhone 4

Comment: What device/OS are you trying to run this on?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like it's a [known issue](https://devforums.apple.com/message/414203#414203) when using double precision.

Solution: Use single-precision, i.e. Floats.

Answer (score 0):

I am using sgesv_ (single-precison) to solve a 1200x1200 equation system.
The execution time on an iPhone 4 is 1.1 s, compared to 60 s when using my old "manual" method.

Answer (score -2):

LAPACK isn't available on ios devices - only BLAS and vDSP. It works on the simulator because that library is available on mac. [iOS Accelerate Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Accelerate/Reference/AccelerateFWRef/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009465)

Comment: I beg to differ. With IOS 4.0, Apple introduced LAPACK functions into Accelerate for iPhone. [Changelog here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#releasenotes/General/iPhone40APIDiffs/).